# Add dependencies to existing make targets

Tags: makefile

#### Condition 0:

Say, I have several source codes, `a.c, b.c, ..., z.c`, and I want a rule to have each of them compiled. Here is a solution:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<
```

#### Condition 1:

Then I introduce a header `c.h` used in `c.c`, and another header `e.h` used in `c.c` and `e.c`, and things become complex:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

c.o: c.c c.h e.h
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

e.o: e.c e.h
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<
```

#### My question:

Based on the solution of condition 1, is there something like `add_dependency` in `make` to simplify the solution and obtain something like the following one?

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

add_dependency(c.o, c.h e.h)
add_dependency(e.o, e.h)
```

Or, what do you think is a better solution to condition 1?

**EDITED:**

Thanks for the kind notice @ctheo :)
Yes I did have a look at `autotools` and understood that shall satisfy all my needs. However what I'm dealing with is an existing project and its `Makefile` contains other directives dealing with codes in `C++`, and I think for now I'd better just modify a few lines instead of port the whole `Makefile` to `autotools`, unless I couldn't find a satisfying solution without introducing `autotools`. :)

Comment: autotools do exactly what you ask for.

Comment: @ctheo Thanks for the kind notice, and I've updated the question body as the reply to your comment. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At first I did not expected to exist a solution for this. It seemed to me that it was covered by `autotools`. However, after some search, I found [this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Rules.html#Multiple-Rules) of GNU/make manual.

It states that :

> One file can be the target of **several rules**. All the prerequisites mentioned in all the rules **are merged** into one list of prerequisites for the target.

So there is a solution for your query

```
c.o: c.h e.h
e.o: e.h

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<
```

Thanks for insisting. I learned something today :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition, the `.o` files in your example all depend on a `.h` file with the same stem, so you can generalise that part of your rules too:

```
c.o: e.h

%.o: %.c %.h
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<
```

This way, your “normal” situations are covered entirely by the rule that triggers compilation and your “unusual” situations stand out because those are the only additional rules.